# Need help in retrieving this from appSettings without hardcoding

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, configuration, appsettings

I need some help in retrieving this from appSettings using disctionary without hardcoding the value.

```
   "HMAC": {
      "MLC": {
        "Server": {
           "PE": {
             "ApiKey": null,
             "SecretKey": null
             },
           "DNB": {
             "ApiKey": null,
             "SecretKey": null
           }
          },
        "Clients": {
             "Billing": {
                  "ApiKey": null,
                  "SecretKey": null
                 },
             "Finance": {
                  "ApiKey": null,
                  "SecretKey": null
             }
          }
      }
   },
```

Currently This is how I have in my appSettings to get the apiKeys. But it without the MLC layer. I am lost on how to add that other layer to get the Server or Client keys.

```
    public class HMAC
    {

        public IDictionary<string, HMACSettings> Server { get; set; } = null!;
        public IDictionary<string, HMACSettings> Clients { get; set; } = null!;
        public HMACSettings? GetServer(string KeyName)
        {
            return GetValue(this.Server, KeyName);
        }
        public HMACSettings? GetClients(string KeyName)
        {
            return GetValue(this.Clients, KeyName);
        }
        public HMACSettings? GetValue(IDictionary<string, HMACSettings> HmacCollection, string KeyName)
        {
            if (HmacCollection?.Count() > 0 && HmacCollection.ContainsKey(KeyName))
            {
                return HmacCollection[KeyName];
            }
            return null;
        }
    }


    public class HMACSettings
    {
        public string ApiKey { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string SecretKey { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
```

I am using .Net Core and so I have instantiated the HMac and when I need the keys I am just calling

```
    this.hmacSettings = hmac.Value?.GetServer(mlcKey);
```

How to add another layer MLC to the dicstionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can always nest Dictionaries. I took the liberty of adding a class though as it seems "Servers" and "Clients" are kind of constant in your case.

So the new class looks like this:

```
public class ComputerGroup
{
    public IDictionary<string, HMACSettings> Servers { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, HMACSettings>();
    public IDictionary<string, HMACSettings> Clients { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, HMACSettings>();
}
```

Your existing HMAC class got modified and now looks like this:

```
public class HMAC
{
    public IDictionary<string, ComputerGroup> TopLevelGroup { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, ComputerGroup>();

    public HMACSettings? GetServer(string topLevelKey, string keyName)
    {
        if (TopLevelGroup.ContainsKey(topLevelKey))
        {
            var topGroup = TopLevelGroup[topLevelKey];
            if (topGroup.Servers.ContainsKey(keyName))
            {
                return topGroup.Servers[keyName];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public HMACSettings? GetClients(string topLevelKey, string keyName)
    {
        if (TopLevelGroup.ContainsKey(topLevelKey))
        {
            var topGroup = TopLevelGroup[topLevelKey];
            if (topGroup.Clients.ContainsKey(keyName))
            {
                return topGroup.Clients[keyName];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

For testing purposes I populated the settings like this:

```
hmac.TopLevelGroup.Add(
    "MLC", new ComputerGroup()
    {
        Servers = new Dictionary<string, HMACSettings>() {
            { "PE", new HMACSettings() { ApiKey = "pe-key", SecretKey = "pe-sec" } },
            { "DNB", new HMACSettings() { ApiKey = "dnb-key", SecretKey = "dnb-sec" } }
        },
        Clients = new Dictionary<string, HMACSettings>() {
            { "Billing", new HMACSettings() { ApiKey = "billing-key", SecretKey = "billing-sec" } },
            { "Finance", new HMACSettings() { ApiKey = "finance-key", SecretKey = "finance-sec" } }
        }
    }
);
```

Querying the settings with `hmac.GetServer("MLC", "PE");` returns `// settings = HMACSettings { ApiKey = "pe-key", SecretKey = "secret-key" }`

Answer (score 0):

There is very simple way to get value`hmac.Value?.GetServer(mlcKey);` and convert to you custom type :

```
string mlckey ="PE";
this.hmacSettings = configuration.GetSection("HMAC").GetSection("MLC").GetSection("Server").GetSection(mlckey).Get<HMACSettings>();
```

You need to inject configuration from IConfiguration to use it.